# Android ImageView get bitmap after zoom using setImageMatrix

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, pinchzoom

In Android I have an ImageView which user can manipulate the position and zoom level in the UI.

Is it possible to get the zoomed image (changed image) from the ImageView instead of original one.

Here are the methods I tried but no use.

```
imageView.buildDrawingCache(true);
Bitmap bmp = imageView.getDrawingCache(true);
```

I can get the Matrix but don't know how to use it.

```
Matrix m =  imageView.getImageMatrix();
```

Answer (score 1):

The zoom effect is applied at the Canvas level. So, what you can do is get the current Canvas augmentations and then draw your Bitmap into a new one with the changes.

```
Matrix transformMatrix =  imageView.getImageMatrix()

Bitmap original = bmp;

Bitmap adjusted = Bitmap.createBitmap(original.getWidth(),
 original.getHeight(),
 original.getConfig());
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(adjusted);
canvas.setMatrix(transformMatrix);
canvas.drawBitmap(original, 0, 0, null);

//at this point adjusted bitmap contains the zoomed image
```

Answer (score 0):

When you get a Matrix from an ImageView, make changes to t, then use imageView.[setImageMatrix(m)](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageMatrix%28android.graphics.Matrix%29) apply the changes back to the ImageView.  You will want to look into using one of the [postScale()](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html#postScale%28float,%20float%29) matrix methods to make a change in the size of image rendered.